# Redirect in .htaccess when page numbers are both in a query parameter and in the path

Tags: url, 301-redirect, url-parameters, pagination, query-string

My blog is creating duplicate pagination, and Google understands this as duplicate content.
How to 301 redirect pagination as in the following examples?

- `https://example.com/page/33?page=34`
  to: `https://example.com/page/33`
- `https://example.com/page/23?page=25`
  to: `https://example.com/page/23`

I need redirect all `?page=` to your correct link /number

Recently, I was able to remove broken links `?m=0` with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=[01]$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=[0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^/?(page/[0-9]+)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

When the query string has a page number in it like `page=34` and the path is also a page number like `/page/23`, then redirect to remove the query string.

- `[0-9]+` is one or more digits, ie a number
- `^` and `$` are "starts with" and "ends with" respectively, the query string will only match if the page parameter is the only thing in it.
- `^/?` is starts with an optional slash so that this rule can work in *.htaccess* or in apache conf files.
- `()` are capturing parenthesis whose contents are then available in `$1`